# Can't import JSON in Excel 2016 using "Get & Transform" feature

Tags: microsoft-excel, json

According to Microsoft's [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-a-JSON-file-f65207ab-d957-4bf0-bec3-a08bb53cd4c0) I should be able to import JSON files by:

> Click the Data tab, then Get Data > From File > From JSON.

[image: Data Tab]

[image: Not there]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the json file is on your computer, a file, you can enter '***file:\c:\filename.json***' in place of the web url. Don't include the '. The easiest way is to use the file browser and copy the path to the file and then add the file name at the end.

Comment: Note that this does not refer to "From Web" in the ribbon as per the question asker's screenshot, but under "New Query" > "From Other Sources" > "From Web"

Comment: On Windows 10 I had to use three /// as in: file:///D:/filename.json

Answer (score 8):

I ran into the same situation, and then found a work around on the following page:
https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Get-and-Transform-Data/Missing-JSON-option-at-Data-gt-New-query-gt-From-File/td-p/69747

In short, the steps are to:

1. New Query -> From Other Sources -> From Web;
2. Type in (or Copy-Paste) an url to you Json data and hit OK button;
3. After Query Edit opens, right-click a document icon on a query dashboard and select JSON and your data is transformed to a table data format.

Thanks to 'Good Boy' who provided the work around in the article mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I found this can also be done by using From File > From Text:

[image]

Make sure you change the extension filter to "All Files"so you can find your file:

[image]

Excel will detect that the file is JSON and parse it that way. No special tricks needed. :)